# Can anyone tell me how can I get the following output?

Tags: python

**Here is my code;**

```
file_name = ['0a57bd3e-e558-4534-8315-4b0bd53df9d8.jpeg', '20d721fc-c443-49b2-aece-fd760f13ff7e.jpeg']
img_id = {}
images = []
for e, i in enumerate(range(len(file_name))):
    img_id['file_name'] = file_name[e]
    images.append(img_id)
print(images)
```

**The output is;**

```
[{'file_name': '20d721fc-c443-49b2-aece-fd760f13ff7e.jpeg'}, {'file_name': '20d721fc-c443-49b2-aece-fd760f13ff7e.jpeg'}]
```

**I want it to be;**

```
[{'file_name': '0a57bd3e-e558-4534-8315-4b0bd53df9d8.jpeg'}, {'file_name': '20d721fc-c443-49b2-aece-fd760f13ff7e.jpeg'}]
```

I don't know, why it is saves only the last file name in the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the data stored in `img_id` because you are using the same dictionary with the same key (`file_name`). You can either reset the `img_id` variable to an empty dictionary within your for loop or use a simpler list comprehension:

```
file_name = ['0a57bd3e-e558-4534-8315-4b0bd53df9d8.jpeg', '20d721fc-c443-49b2-aece-fd760f13ff7e.jpeg']

images = []
for e, i in enumerate(range(len(file_name))):
    img_id = {}
    img_id['file_name'] = file_name[e]
    images.append(img_id)

# or
[{"file_name": x} for x in file_name]
```

Comment: hahha, how can I miss that!!! Thank you